# Build a React Native library with other RN module as a dependency

Tags: react-native

I want to build a React Native library which just wrapper two others RN projects and delivery it with some new modifications. Is this the right way to create an RN Library/Module?

For example, I tried to create a module using the project called "react-native-create-library", and I want to add an RN project as a dependency, but this project needs to be configured making changes on some files like "AndroidManisfest.xml", "settings.gradle" and so on.

Can someone explain if it's possible to create an RN module which has others RN Modules as a dependency?